# when i click the button the action listener on a button it keeps looping and it does not stop till i stop the code

Tags: java, swing, button

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    String EditableText = textField.getText(); //gets the text from a text box
                    System.out.println(EditableText);//prints it
                    wordParser.mainProcessor(EditableText);//sends it for processing for the main app

                }
            });
```

but when i run it , enter some text in the text box and click on the button it loops and spams in the console

i guess something is wrong with the action listener

one more thing that happens is the button greys outand i cant revert it until i stop the program

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some issue with the

```
wordParser.mainProcessor(EditableText); //sends it for processing for the main app
```

Maybe some loop issues which blocks main thread.